# Asp.Net MVC - Linq Sorting Question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have a MVC application that I'm near completing.  But I have a situation that cannot figure out the syntax for.

What I want to do is to sort on two columns  When I use the syntax below, it sorts by one column, then the next.

```
        public IQueryable<vw_FormIndex> FindAllFormsVw(int companyIdParam)
    {
        return _db.vw_FormIndexes.Where(d => d.companyID == companyIdParam).OrderBy(d => d.formSortOrder).OrderBy(d => d.formCustNumber);
    }
```

Suggestions Please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use .OrderBy().ThenBy();

Answer (score 5):

I think you want ThenBy

```
public IQueryable<vw_FormIndex> FindAllFormsVw(int companyIdParam)
{
    return _db.vw_FormIndexes.Where(d => d.companyID == companyIdParam).OrderBy(d => d.formSortOrder).ThenBy(d => d.formCustNumber);
}
```

More on ThenBy operator [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/04/16/thenby-operator-part-14.aspx).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `ThenBy`?

```
_db.vw_FormIndexes.Where(d => d.companyID == companyIdParam).OrderBy(d => d.formSortOrder).ThenBy(d => d.formCustNumber);
```